# How can i select just one row in Oracle by row id?

Tags: oracle

I have used mysql database in my application, but I want to migrate to Oracle.

The problem is in that query:

```
select * from users limit ?,1;"
```

That query returns every row one by one depending on ?.

How can i do that in oracle?

Comment: As i know oracle has no limit with offset.

Comment: Newer Oracle versions have OFFSET / FETCH FIRST!

Comment: In MySQL is OK, but I don't know can I receive just one row like I do in MySQL with LIMIT.

Comment: Thank you @jarlh but my Oracle not recognized OFFSET. Another solution?

Comment: Do you want the row to be sorted in any particular order or you want any random row?

Comment: Then there's a row_number (or similar, can't remember), that you can use.

Comment: I will give an integer and I want to result for 1 => first row, for 2=> second row and so on.

Comment: There is nothing called **FIRST ROW** in Oracle, unless you specify an **ORDER BY** clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (select rownum r, u.* from users u ) where r=1;
```

or if you want it sorted (replace x by columnnumber or columnname):

```
select * from (select rownum r, u.* from users u order by x) where r=1;
```

Comment: That is going to give you any random row.

Answer (score 2):

On Oracle 12c, you could use the **row limiting** feature using **FETCH FIRST** clause.

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal, deptno FROM emp ORDER BY empno DESC
  2  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

     EMPNO        SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7934       1300         10

SQL>
```

Prior 12c solution is **ROWNUM**, however, if you want the row to be first sorted, then you need to do it in a sub-query -

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal, deptno FROM
  2    ( SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY empno DESC
  3    ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

     EMPNO        SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7934       1300         10

SQL>
```

If the order doesn't matter to you, if you just want any random row, simply use **ROWNUM**.

Depending on your requirement, you could also use **ANALYTIC functions** such as `ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK`.